# Cron Job PHP script execution time report

Tags: php, cron

My question is simple: I want to know how long a PHP script is taking to execute. On top of this, I am executing it via cron. Now, I could do something via the PHP code itself to get the execution time start/end, however I wondered if there was something via the cron command that I could add to get that emailed to me, in milliseconds?

Currently I am using:

```
/usr/bin/php -q httpsdocs/folder/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which runs my script and stops all errors/output getting emailed to me. Can I change the above to get the execution time emailed to me somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `time` command like this:

```
/usr/bin/time /usr/bin/php -q httpsdocs/folder/script.php > /var/log/crontiming
```

Comment: The good news is I got some ms timings.. the bad news is that they were too small to be correct. I also got Permission Denied on /var/log/crontiming

Comment: Does the user that runs cron have permission to write on `/var/log/crontiming`?

Comment: can I get it emailed rather than logged?

Comment: There's a `MAILTO` variable you can set in the crontab file, so it automatically sends an email to that address on every run. http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html

Comment: Quoting http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html: In addition to LOGNAME, HOME, and SHELL, cron will look at MAILTO if
     it has any reason to send mail as a result of running commands in
     `this' crontab. If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to
     the user so named.

Answer (score 5):

```
/usr/bin/time /usr/bin/php -q httpsdocs/folder/script.php
 | mail -s "Some Subject" you@youremailid.com
```

:-)

Comment: That sends me an empty email :)

Comment: Remove the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part.

Comment: you're right, although I simply removed everything after the script path. It defaults to mailto as ncuesta states

Answer (score 1):

By the given script you can change the cron job execution time.

```
$aCronList = array();
$result = -1;
exec('crontab -l', $aCronList, $result);
foreach($aCronList AS $item)
{
    // Find what you want, replace the times
}

$sCronList = implode(PHP_EOL, $aCronList);
exec('crontab < ' . $sCronList);
```